# Proper and secure way to select subset of data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, schema

A scheduled task does geocoding via a command line script and therefore needs to access some data (addresses to geocode) stored in Microsoft SQL Server.

This data belongs to schema **A** and consists of data from more than one table.

I thought about

- creating a sql server login, schema and user **B**
- creating a view **A.VIEW1** selecting from **A.TABLE_X** and **A.TABLE_Y**
- granting **SELECT** permission on **A.VIEW1** TO **B**

Since the view references other tables, selecting with **B** from **A.VIEW1** throws a permission error:

> SELECT permission denied on object '**A.TABLE_X**', database '...', schema '...'.

Is there any alternative to GRANT SELECT on **A.TABLE_X**, **A.TABLE_Y**, ... TO **B**?
Because if I do so, **B** can read **all** data from those tables, can't it?

I don't want **B** to be able to do so, since the sql server credentials for **B** will be stored in plaintext on file system or in task scheduler. (Any alternative?)

**A.TABLE_X** and **A.TABLE_Y** contain customer-related data like bank account numbers etc.
I could limit GRANT to specific columns, but I still dislike this idea.

Another way would be to fill a temp table before with a stored proc **A.PROC_FILL**, but granting EXEC to **B** would also be not enough, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you grant `exec` permission for a stored procedure `reportproc` to user `report_user` then by default the user will be able to run that procedure with the permissions of the creator and see the results without needing permissions to underlying tables.

That procedure could just be a `select`, rather than filling a table.

```
create proc reportproc as
begin
    select * from a.table_x inner join a.table_y on tablex.id = table_y.id
end
go
grant exec on reportproc to reportuser
```

With views on tables from different schemas the situation is a little more complex. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx

Comment: This does not work for me. **A** can select from _a.TABLE_X_. And **A** can exec _reportproc_. But **B** (reportuser) can't exec after grant.

Comment: I need to add that there's another underlying table **C.TABLE_Z**, **A** can select from.

Comment: @Mike What does it say when you try with user B?

Comment: It throws the error I described in my initial post: _SELECT permission denied on object 'C.TABLE_Z', database '...', schema '...'._

Comment: Is C a schema or a database?

Comment: I read the article about ownership chains. So it's just impossible to allow **B** to select from **A.VIEW1** referencing **C.TABLE_Z** without granting explicit SELECT permission ON **C.TABLE_Z** to **B**, correct? I found the [EXECUTE AS clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx), but this does not work for views or table-valued functions, only **procedures**. Declaring a stored proc **A.reportproc** WITH EXECUTE AS _OWNER_, it works fine. Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: **C** is a schema, same database.

Comment: I personally would prefer a `proc with execute as` to exposing a table or a view, but such discussions can get religious. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with `execute as` - in fact it makes the behaviour more explict.